# ChartUtilities.apply CurrentTheme make NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, struts2, jfreechart

I'm using `strut2` with `JFReeChart` 1.0.13

And some reason a i can't use `ChartUtilities.apply CurrentTheme`.
The libraray is imported.

I want to try one of the example.

but it makes exception:

`org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities.applyCurrentTheme(Lorg/jfree/chart/JFreeChart;)V` at

I try to use `public static ChartTheme getChartTheme()` but the same result

```
    private static JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset categorydataset)
{
    JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Open Source Projects By Licence", "Licence", "Project Count", categorydataset, PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, false, true, false);
    TextTitle texttitle = new TextTitle("Source: Freshmeat (http://www.freshmeat.net/)", new Font("Dialog", 0, 10));
    texttitle.setPosition(RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
    jfreechart.addSubtitle(texttitle);
    **ChartUtilities.applyCurrentTheme(jfreechart);**

    CategoryPlot categoryplot = (CategoryPlot)jfreechart.getPlot();
    categoryplot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
    categoryplot.getDomainAxis().setMaximumCategoryLabelWidthRatio(0.8F);
    NumberAxis numberaxis = (NumberAxis)categoryplot.getRangeAxis();
    numberaxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
    BarRenderer barrenderer = (BarRenderer)categoryplot.getRenderer();

    barrenderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
    StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator standardcategorytooltipgenerator = new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator("{1}: {2} projects", new DecimalFormat("0"));
    barrenderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(standardcategorytooltipgenerator);
    GradientPaint gradientpaint = new GradientPaint(0.0F, 0.0F, Color.blue, 0.0F, 0.0F, new Color(0, 0, 64));

    barrenderer.setSeriesPaint(0, gradientpaint);
    return jfreechart;
}
```

How can it solved this problem?

If i comment this line then is no error, but the chart is not good.

Edit:

I upgrage the version to 1.0.15 as Roman C sugested 
After that the problem is fixed.